# C# Windows service not starting

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I try to create a windows service which automatically startsup.
I am able to install and deinstall the service. If I try to start it, I get following error message: "Der Dienst antwortete nicht rechtzeitig auf die Start- oder Steueranfrage". (I try to translate) "The service don't respont in time on start or control request".

Here is my poor code

```
    public class LisaServerService: System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
{
    private Program lisaServerServiceProgram;

    public static string LisaServiceName = "LISA-ServerService";

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LisaServerService lisaServerService = new LisaServerService();

        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            lisaServerService.OnStart(args);
            Console.WriteLine("I am a service. Normally you can't see the console... just ignore me");
            Console.ReadLine();
            lisaServerService.OnStop();
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(lisaServerService);
        }
    }

    public LisaServerService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.CanShutdown = true;
        this.ServiceName = "LISA - ServerService";
        this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        this.lisaServerServiceProgram = new Program();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        lisaServerServiceProgram.Start(null);
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        lisaServerServiceProgram.Stop();
        base.OnStop();
    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        OnStop();
        base.OnShutdown();
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
    public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
        Logger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Information;
        Logger.LogRange = LogRange.Write;
        Logger.Log("Logger initialized");
    }

    public void Start(string[] args)
    {
        DatabaseHandler.StartDatabase();
        NetworkHandler.StartNetwork();
        Logger.Log("Service started");
    }
```

if I run the service as a console program, it works fine.
So the db connection + logger are working fine too. (Also within < 10ms)

Comment: What do the constructors of `Program` and `LisaServerService` look like?

Comment: I'd say that your OnStart method never returns.. Does it?

Comment: Any hint on the event viewer?

Comment: Maybe the credentials running the service are insufficient for access to the database?  Also I get the feeling it would be best practice to separate the service itself from the main function.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and see if it throws an exception somewhere?

Comment: Yes. No errors. @Subterfuge Now you say it, i think you are right. Where are the services in the windows folder located? Because I load the credentials from a file. And why do you think I should seperate it?

Comment: @user1416994 Honestly it just doesn't seem like best practice.  In the past I have made a service class and used the Program class as the entry point, calling ServiceBase.Run() passing it an array of servicebase containing the services I want to start (which can be just one).  At any rate, services will be wherever you installed them from, as for their working path, I **think** it's Windows\System32.  But don't quote me on that.  May be better to just set a breakpoint somewhere and do a watch on System.IO.GetCurrentDirectory().

Comment: ofc if I set a breakpoint its the executing folder (debug) :/
I checked the path in the "Services" http://i28i.img-up.net/screenf1d2.png

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the service in interactive mode it's waiting for the console here:

```
if (Environment.UserInteractive)
{
    lisaServerService.OnStart(args);
    Console.WriteLine("I am a service. Normally you can't see the console... just ignore me");
    Console.ReadLine();
    ...
```

That is likely preventing the service from responding properly to indicate it is started.

Comment: I removed the lines, but same result